# alternative for 'hdfs dfs'

Tags: command-line, hdfs

The HDFS `hdfs dfs` command is quite unwieldily. For example, every time you want to list files, you need to type `hdfs dfs -ls`. Is there a straightforward way, other than command-line aliases, to get a more usable command? One for which you don't need to type a dash before every command?

Right now the only idea I have is:

```
alias dls="hdfs dfs -ls"
```

Comment: Why do you not find aliases straightforward? You could equally well set up separate shell scripts if you find commands external to the shell preferable.

Comment: Because I'd like to have more state and intelligence in the command. For example, an "ls" command that views either on HDFS or the local file system. I'm not sure. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: OK, set up a `myls` script. Have it parse its arguments enough to see if they reference an HDFS path and either call `hdfs dfs -ls` or `/bin/ls`

Comment: Right, but `ls` is just one of many commands that `hdfs dfs` supports. So I'm looking to see if anyone has done this already. The poor usability of `hdfs dfs` is kind of odd.

Comment: `hdfs` already groups most of the utilities one uses maintaining HDFS. HDFS is *not* a Unix file system, so you do need different utilities than when maintaining Unix file systems. So do network mounted file systems. Try `mknod` on an NFS or CIFS mounted directory...